# Is there a way to produce different resolutions of same image at once

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I was downloading wallpapers from https://wallpapersden.com/street-fighter-fortnite-wallpaper/ .
When I clicked on the download button another page opened
"https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/street-fighter-fortnite_bGtoaW6UmZqaraWkpJRmbmdlrWZlbWU.jpg "
I want to know what is `images.wallpapers.com` . Is this another website?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question

Comment: @JohnConde do you know how can I make different resolutions of same image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`images.wallpapersden.com` is a subdomian of `wallpapersden.com` where they store there images. They have created it for convenience in order to handle their images better. it is same as `drive.google.com` and `mail.google.com`.